# TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/1/

Tags: python, django

I got an error,
TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/1/
templates/polls/detail.html  . I want to show detail.html.

Traceback is

```
Traceback:

File "/Users/XXX/django/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/XXX/django/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  130.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/XXX/django/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/XXX/djangostudy/polls/views.py" in detail
  43.         'question': obj,

File "/Users/XXX/django/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/Users/XXX/django/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  61.         template = get_template(template_name, using=using)

File "/Users/XXX/django/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  19.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/1/
Exception Value: templates/polls/detail.html
```

My forms.py is like

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(max_length=100,required=False,label='テキスト')

class VoteForm(forms.Form):
    choice = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=None,
        label='選択',
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        empty_label=None,
        error_messages={
            'required':"You didn't select a choice.",
            'invalid_choice':"invalid choice.",
        },
    )

    def __init__(self,question,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['choice'].queryset = question.choice_set.all()
```

Setting of radio button is written in detail.html,like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'poll_vote' question.id %}" method="post">
<!--<form action="" method="post">-->
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
    {% endfor %}
    <!--{{ form }}-->
    <input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
</html>
```

views.py is

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils.html import mark_safe
from .models import Question
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import Http404
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404,redirect
from .models import Choice
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .forms import MyForm
from .forms import VoteForm


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request,'polls/index.html',{
        'questions': Question.objects.all(),
    })

def detail(request,pk):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Question,pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = VoteForm(question=obj,data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('polls:results',pk)
    else:
        form = VoteForm(question=obj)
    return render(request,'templates/polls/detail.html',{
        'form':form,
        'question': obj,
    })

def vote(request,pk):
    pass

def results(request,pk):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Question,pk=pk)
    return render(request,'polls/results.html',{
        'question':obj,
    })

def form_test(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        #request.POST???
        form = MyForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pass
    else:
        form = MyForm()
    return render(request,'polls/form.html',{
        'form':form,
    })
```

I think the place of loading template, which is detail.html

```
  return render(request,'templates/polls/detail.html',{
        'form':form,
        'question': obj,
    })
```

,so I cannot understand why detail.html is not shown here.How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are telling Django to use `templates/polls/detail.html`. This means Django will look for `polls/templates/templates/polls/detail.html`, which probably isn't what you want.

You haven't said where your template is, but I'm assuming it's at `polls/templates/polls/detail.html`. In this case, you should change the view to:

```
return render(request,'polls/detail.html', {
    'form':form,
    'question': obj,
})
```

Comment: thx,my web site works rightly!!!But I cannot understand why changing 'templates/polls/detail.html' into 'polls/detail.html' can fix the error.Why?

Comment: Django searches your `polls/templates/` folder for the template. When you use `templates/polls/detail.html`, Django looks for `polls/templates/templates/polls/detail.html` which doesn't exist. You don't include `templates` in any of your other views, so you shouldn't for this one either.

Comment: Imagine you have to search for `templates/polls/detail.html` in your `polls/templates/`, you don't have any folder called  `templates` in your `polls/templates`, do you? 
You don't have to specify `templates` because django knows, but you have to specify `polls` as a namespace, in this way, django knows that those templates are for `polls`.